# Excel VBA: How to Extend a Range Given a Current Selection

Tags: excel, vba, selection

I want to do something like:

```
E18-(1,1) &":" &E18+(1,1)
```

My intent is to keep the selection of range `E18` (value = B) and extend the selection to `D16:F20`.

[image: Cell_Image_Excel_Highlighted_B]

If I have a cell's range of `E18` and I want to extend the range to `D16:F20`, how can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by extend. If you already know your range ex `D16:F20` then why not directly use it to select it?

Comment: This is an example, assume if I know a range of the cell which is can be anywhere in the sheet. And I want to make a selection that include surrounding area of this cell. So I want to extend/expand.

Comment: ok will there be only one cell to start with?

Comment: Yes, only one. Which is a cell address A1, B3, etc

Comment: I have tried resize but it does not seem to work

Comment: `Set newRange = Range("E18").Offset(-2,-1).Resize(5,3)`

Comment: +1 Nicely detailed and explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Range(Cells(WorksheetFunction.Max(1, Selection.Row - 1), _
      WorksheetFunction.Max(1, Selection.Column - 1)), _
      Cells(WorksheetFunction.Min(Selection.Worksheet.Rows.Count, _
      Selection.Row + 1), _
      WorksheetFunction.Min(Selection.Worksheet.Columns.Count, _
      Selection.Column + 1))).Select
```

upd: thanks Siddharth Rout for formating my msg

Answer (score 16):

You mean like this?

**SYNTAX**

ExpandRange [*Range*], [*Number of Col on left*], [*Number of Rows on Top*], [*Number of Col on right*], [*Number of Rows down*]

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print ExpandRange(Range("B5"), 1, 1, 1, 1)            '<~~ $A$4:$C$6
    Debug.Print ExpandRange(Range("A1"), 1, 1, 1, 1)            '<~~ Error
    Debug.Print ExpandRange(Range("XFD4"), 1, 1, 1, 1)          '<~~ Error
    Debug.Print ExpandRange(Range("XFD1048576"), 1, 1, 1, 1)    '<~~ Error
    Debug.Print ExpandRange(Range("E5"), 1, 1, 1, 1)            '<~~ $D$4:$F$6
End Sub

Function ExpandRange(rng As Range, lft As Long, tp As Long, _
rt As Long, dwn As Long) As String
    If rng.Column - lft < 1 Or _
       rng.Row - tp < 1 Or _
       rng.Column + rt > ActiveSheet.Columns.Count Or _
       rng.Row + dwn > ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then
        ExpandRange = "Error"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ExpandRange = Range(rng.Offset(-1 * tp, -1 * lft).Address & ":" & _
                        rng.Offset(dwn, rt).Address).Address
End Function
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is the simple code that I use to resize an existing selection.

```
Selection.Resize(Selection.Rows.Count + 5, Selection.Columns.Count + 50).Select
```

This will add 5 to the row count and 50 to the column count.  Adapt to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Offset()` which is richer than VBA's Offset and does everything required by the question.
I think it does what Siddharth Rout ExpandRange does, without the need of a UDF.

Comment: Just quick question - I think I might just post here - how do I add this range to a listbox (as values).  I tried <code>Listbox1.List = ExpandRange("A1",0,0,1,1)</code> I also tried to define a variant but it returns error: Could not set the List Property.

Comment: @NCC: What do you want to do? Assign the values of the resulting range to a listbox?

Comment: Yes,  Siddharth Rout. It seems that I do not known this concept well because sometimes I have it work, sometimes I do not.

Comment: I have tried but I always got Could not set the List Property when I used <code>.List</code>

Answer (score 2):

### **How to select and extend a range from anywhere on a sheet, to anywhere on a sheet.**

*This is my first post.  I know I'm a little bit late to the party, and it's obvious to me that most of the people here are far far more experienced and skilled than I am. So I doubt my solutions include much of their "big picture" nuanced considerations, but I've verified they work for me and I hope they work for all of you too.*

Okay, so back to the question.
Here is how I do it.

- **Example One**
  To do this for the exact scenario posed by your question, if you’re starting at E18 and you want to extend the range to D16:F20, use the code below. As long as you have room for the full range, your active cell can actually be *anywhere*, and that range will follow it.

  `Range(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, -1), ActiveCell.Offset(2, 1)).Select`
- **Example Two**
  If you’ve already selected a range, and then you want to expand it further (let’s say and additional 2 rows down and 1 column to the right), then do this:

  `Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(2, 1)).Select`
- **Example Three**
  If you want to select a range of all the contiguous cells containing data, starting from the active cell and continuing down until it reaches a blank cell, *and then also add the cells from 1 column to the left*, then do this:

  `Range(ActiveCell, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1)).Select`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning an absolute address, I modifying the syntax above to return a range. Credit goes to Siddharth Rout = )

```
Function ExpandRG(rng As Variant, lft As Long, tp As Long, rt As Long, dwn As Long) _
 As Range
 Set ws = rng.Parent
If rng.Column - lft < 1 Or _
   rng.Row - tp < 1 Or _
   rng.Column + rt > ActiveSheet.Columns.Count Or _
   rng.Row + dwn > ActiveSheet.Rows.Count Then
        MsgBox "Out of range"
        Exit Function
End If

 Set rng = ws.Range(rng.Offset(-1 * tp, -1 * lft).Address & ":" & _
                    rng.Offset(dwn, rt).Address)                        
End Function

Sub aa()
Dim ori_add, O_add, New_add As Range
Set ori_add = Range("B2")
Set O_add = ori_add

Call ExpandRG(ori_add, 1, 1, 1, 1)
Set New_add = ori_add

MsgBox "Original address " & O_add.Address & ", new address is" & New_add.Address
End Sub
```