# Compare column`s and select rows

Tags: excel, vba

How can I take each number from column J, and select all rows where that number is in column F..?
Example:

- Take first number from column J (11123)
- Search column F and select all rows that first number (11123) is value
- Take next number from column J (11124)
- Search column F and ADD to selected rows from previous search,
  rows that containing number (11124)
- And so on until end of column J

[image]

I try this, but I getting error:

```
Sub qTest()

Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Dim fRNG As Range
Dim aRNG As Range

Set fRNG = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").End(xlDown))
Set aRNG = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2", Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J2").End(xlDown))

aRNG.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=fRNG, Unique:=False

Dim aADD As String
aADD = aRNG.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address

aRNG.Parent.ShowAllData

Range(aADD).EntireRow.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: A piece of your puzzle will be incrementing your selected range.  Here is a [solid answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692213/excel-vba-how-to-extend-a-range-given-a-current-selection/10692557#10692557) that may help with that.

Comment: Thanks for advice.. I try different approaches that I find, but nothing... I`m not so good in VBA.. :-(

Comment: I`m close.. but Application-defined or object-defined error is killing me... :-(

Comment: Do you just want to end up with a bunch of selected rows?  What do you want to do with the selection afterwards?  It might be easier if you include that step in your question too.

Answer (score 0):

With what you need to achieve, I think it's much easier to copy/cut the data in column J (from J2 to Jxxx) then paste at the bottom of data in column F, then do Data Sort on column F. No VBA codes required!

Comment: Yes but in col J there is 1996 different zip codes and in col F there is 628790 numbers

Comment: @Art-of-Life So need code to move these 1996 zip codes in Col J to bottom of Col F and invoke Ascending Sort on Col J? Do you need to fill in other columns say Col G before sorting?